# C library include

Tags: c, include

I write C library and  I don't know how make some functions invisible for user (which are used to implement functionality). There is any way in C? And my second question is: when I include some library in .h or .c file (let's see  math.h) is there any problem when user declare the same header in his program (which use my library of course)?

And how about structure? Is there any key word?

Comment: 1. Please explain why the user would see the functions, provide a header with just the functions you want to export. 2. With MSVC you must explicitly export the symbols you want, and gcc has a visibility option too. 3. No, you can include a header multiple times provided that it has include guards. Standard library headers have them.

Comment: I mean I have some function: tmp1, tmp2, tmp3 which are used by function func. And I want that only func will be visible by user like in standard library. So include and programmer can use only func, not tmp1, tmp2, tmp3

Comment: You declare them `static` and they will have file scope (*it's a very common technique*). But if you don't post the code and why you are having problems it's impossible to help you.

Comment: So I think static resolve my "problem". Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> how to make some functions invisible ?

1. do not declare the function in the header file of your library
2. define the function as `static` in the source file of your library

Example:

**your-lib.h**

```
#ifndef YOUR_LIB_H
#define YOUR_LIB_H

void do_public_stuff(void);

#endif YOUR_LIB_H
```

**your-lib.c**

```
#include "your-lib.h"

// this functions is invisible
static void do_private_stuff(void)
{
    // ...
}

// this functions is visible
void do_public_stuff(void)
{
    // ...
}
```

**user-code.c**

```
#include "your-lib.h"

int main(void)
{
    do_public_stuff();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! This is answer for my question

Answer (score 0):

A usual way is to make implementation functions static that is to declare them with storage specifier `static` and place them in modules with code. So neither header will have references to these functions.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the keyword `static` as the other answers suggested.
But sometimes, the library itself will consist of several source- and object-files, and there might be functions, which have to be used throughout the whole library, but shall not be exported *after linking*.

**Simple example:**

Your library has 3 objects: lib1.o lib2.o util.o

Located in `util.o` are several helper-functions, which are used by `lib1.o` and `lib2.o`. You cannot use static here, because the functions would not be visible to them and linking would fail.

**What you can do:**

Make the helper-functions non-static and provide the linker with a *version script*, which only exports the needed symbols:

```
gcc -shared lib1.o lib2.o util.o -o mylib.so -Wl,--version-script=map
```

The file `map` could have the following content:

```
{
    global: 
        bar;
        baz;
    local: *;
};
```

This would only export the symbols `bar` and `baz` (which are the relevant API-functions for this sample lib), while omitting all other symbols from the symbol table.